# What's the point in the view data of the form being an instance of `data_class`

Tags: forms, symfony

There are many questions on stackoverflow asking about the error from symfony forms which states that the form's **view data** must an instance of the `data_class` option. e.g: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29187899/the-forms-view-data-is-expected-to-be-an-instance-of-class-my-but-is-an)
Now the whole point of [transformation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/form/data_transformers.html) is to obtain something that can be rendered in the view e.g: a string, and to get the model object in the backend, so it doesn't make sense to require that the **view data** is an instance of the `data_class` option, on the contrary, the **model data** is what is supposed to be an instance of `data_class` So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The question you mentioned is about having a **SINGLE** entity expected, but **ARRAY** of entities actual. So expectations about **VIEW** entity transformation result were failed. That means that **VIEW** data does not **represent** the **ENTITY** being instance of **data_class**.

So you either can perform further transformations to fullfil expectations, or relax the expectations by removing `data_class`.

The point you are missing is that **VIEW** data is still the **instance of** `data_class`, but it was normalized and serialized.

Comment: The referenced question might not have been a very good example. You're last statement is the main focus of the question, but it's not justified. You also mention that the  VIEW data might be a serialization of the bound object, but a serialization of an object is not an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not missing anything here. If you check the source code of `Form::getData()` you'll see `return $this->modelData;` there.

So basically you're right. It is required that 'model data' is instance of 'data_class'.

Transformers are responsible to transform 'model data' to 'view data' and back. For example Tags objects array to comma separated string and back to objects.